# Android Sqlite transfer table from one database to another

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I've a requirement in my android app.

There is an already existing database A which has a table T. From the next release of the app, I want to create a new database B and **MOVE** my table from A to B **WITH** all the existing data.

I am guessing there'd be some way to take dump from the existing db and store that in an asset file. And then use that file to restore the table in new db.

Can't store that data in-memory as it might go to inconsistent state if the app is killed in between.

I am not able to find any well-defined way to do this after spending some time searching in the docs/on the forums.

Please help.

Comment: one way is to write records in .txt format and then transfer them into another db

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't clear your requirement. Do you want transfer all exist data from db A to db B?

Comment: @chaunv : not all existing data, only a table from db A to db B.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `ATTACH` command of sqlite. First is by specifying the path of the first database.

```
private static String FIRST_DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath("Sample.sqlite").toString();
```

Then you attach it to secondDb

```
SQLiteDatabase secondDB = secondDBHandler.getWritableDatabase();
secondDB.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + FIRST_DB_PATH + "' AS tempDb");
```

Then do the insert query. **NOTE:** You use secondDB as **main**

```
secondDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO main." + SeconDB_table_name +  "SELECT * FROM tempDb."+ FirstDB_table_name );
```

Then finally detach the first db

```
secondDB.execSQL("DETACH tempDb");
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT:**

Do this for dropping table

```
secondDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main." + SeconDB_table_name);
```

Ok heres how to create a table for secondDB as a copy of the firstDb

```
secondDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE main." + SeconDB_table_name + " AS SELECT * FROM tempDb." + FirstDB_table_name);
```

If what you mean in **comment** is to drop the first table after moving it to second table, then drop it before dettaching

```
secondDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempDb." + FirstDB_table_name);
```

Comment: will try this. And I have to drop that table from the original database. Where do i do that? I can't put that directly in onupgrade, since it might be called before the migration happens

Comment: hey, I've to drop the original table, not the new one.

Comment: Did you mean you drop the firstDB table? why? you're suppose to copy it?

Comment: Not copy, I wanted to move it. Sorry if I was not clear at the beginning.

Comment: Check edited answer. If you still have problem. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169633/discussion-between-android-k-doe-and-yashasvi).